# How to place 'textarea' and 'a' (button) tags side by side in one row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
<div class="row">
   <a class="btn btn btn-success btn-block"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>Ok</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <textarea name="textareaAxs" ></textarea>
   <a class="btn btn btn-danger btn-block"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>Cancel</a>
</div>
```

enter image description here

Comment: [Read the docs](http://getbootstrap.com). "Rows are wrappers for columns... content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.row2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <a class="btn btn btn-success btn-block"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>Ok</a>
</div>
<div class="row2">
   <textarea name="textareaAxs" ></textarea>
   <a class="btn btn btn-danger btn-block"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here some [DOCUMENTATION](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <a class="btn btn btn-success btn-block"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>Ok</a>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" name="textareaAxs" ></textarea>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <a class="input-group-button btn btn btn-danger btn-block"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>Cancel</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```